# PHP 7 with Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: symfony, composer-php, doctrine-odm, php-7

I have a Symfony 2 application that is using Doctrine MongoDB ODM and I'm trying to get this running with PHP 7.

I have installed PHP 7 successfully but installing dependencies through Composer is giving me grief with the following error:

```
doctrine/mongodb 1.0.x-dev requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
```

I managed to install the PHP 7 mongo extension through apt:

```
apt-get install php7.0-mongo
```

Just to be sure, I have also installed the `mongodb` extension through PECL:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-pear php7.0-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

However, I'm still get the error that the mongo extension cannot be found. There seems to be a version discrepancy in that `ext-mongo >=1.2.12` is required but only `1.1.6` was installed::

```
$ php -i | grep mongo
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.6
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.5
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

What is the correct way to install the mongo extension required by Doctrine ODM for PHP 7?

Answer (score 17):

On PHP7 you cannot install `mongo` extension. What you can do, is to install https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter first, then install doctrine.

```
composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter
```

Comment: Ah. OK. So, if I understand correctly, as of this time of writing, Doctrine MongoDB ODM doesn't work on PHP 7. Is that correct?

Comment: That isn't correct, Doctrine Mongodb ODM at the moment depend on old `mongo` extension, but works very well on PHP 7 with `mongo-php-adapter` package installed in project, and `mongodb` php extension.

Comment: Yes. You're right that there is a "third-party" workaround, but Doctrine MongoDB ODM itself doesn't seem to work on PHP 7. I'm concerned about the "Known issues" of the `mongo-php-adapter` though, but I obviously have to try first... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm working on updating a project which already uses doctrine, if you don't want to remove doctrine, require mongo-php-adapter and require doctrine again you can use the --ignore-platform-reqs option:

`composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 11):

in composer.json I added

```
"provide" : {
  "ext-mongo": "*"
},
```

before "require" and this forces to install latest extension

Answer (score -3):

In order to use Symfony with MongoDB you need:

- Symfony : obviously :-) ;
- Symfony Doctrine MongoDB Bundle (doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle): this bundle integrates the Doctrine2 MongoDB Object Document Mapper (ODM) library into Symfony;
- Doctrine MongoDB Object Document Mapper (doctrine/mongodb-odm): library that provides a PHP object mapping functionality for MongoDB;
- MongoDB Adapter (alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter): It provides the API of ext-mongo built on top of mongo-php-library, thus being compatible with PHP 7;
- MongoDB driver library (mongodb/mongodb): provides a high-level abstraction around the lower-level drivers for PHP;
- MongoDB PHP extension: low level driver extension for PHP and HHVM. Please pay attention on the MongoDB driver. Don’t use the legacy MongoDB driver (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php).

You can follow the instructions here:
["How to install Symfony3 with MongoDB"](https://medium.com/@robertodev/how-to-install-symfony3-with-mongodb-5ce5baaee4e7#.8vbpiazep)

It was written for Symfony3 but for Symfony2 is the same issue. The problem was PHP7 + mongodb driver + Doctrine.